# Paypal Payments API

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, payment

Is there a way in PayPal where I can make use of PayPal API to transfer amount to another Bank account?

The transfer will happen only in the US.

I am trying to implement at the backend level and many videos online are showing that it requires human interaction but in my case it should be API driven.

Answer (score 0):

There are very many ways to send money with PayPal, but PayPal only sends money to PayPal accounts / email addresses (absent some premium specialized service such as Hyperwallet)

After money is received to a PayPal account, its owner can withdraw money to their bank whenever they choose.